# Blazor Telerik Grid set cell color from data

Tags: html, blazor, telerik-grid

Trying to set cell background color based on hex code from dataset.  Not seeing a property for the grid itself so I am trying binging style to the object Course.ColorHex value for each row with some sort of property binding.

Course Object

```
public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
        public string CourseDescription { get; set; }
        public string ColorHex { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CourseController : ControllerBase
    {

        private static readonly string[] colorList = new[] { "#ff0000", "##ffff00", "#00ff00", "#00ffff", "#0000ff", "#ff00ff" };

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Course> GetCourses()
        {
            var courses = new List<Course>();

            for (var i = 0; i < colorList.Length; i++)
            {
                var idCount = i + 1;
                var course = new Course()
                {
                    Id = idCount,
                    CourseTitle = $"Course {idCount}",
                    CourseDescription = $"Course {idCount} description",
                    ColorHex = colorList[i]
                };
                courses.Add(course);
            }
            var result = courses.ToArray();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Blazor

```
@page "/grid"
@using TelerikGridColorTest.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http

<h3>Courses</h3>
<TelerikGrid Data="courses">
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="@(nameof(Course.CourseTitle))" />
        <GridColumn Field="@(nameof(Course.CourseDescription))" />
        <GridColumn>
            <Template>
                <div style="background-color: @(nameof(Course.ColorHex)); padding: 10px;"></div>
            </Template>
        </GridColumn>

    </GridColumns>
</TelerikGrid>

@code {
        Course[] courses { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        courses = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Course[]>("Course");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Forgot to one address the field I was working with in the Field property.

```
@page "/grid"
@using TelerikGridColorTest.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http

<h3>Courses</h3>

<TelerikGrid Data="courses">
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="@(nameof(Course.CourseTitle))" />
        <GridColumn Field="@(nameof(Course.CourseDescription))" />
        <GridColumn Field="@(nameof(Course.ColorHex))">
            <Template>
                @{ 
                    var color = context as Course;
                    <div style="background-color: @(color.ColorHex); padding: 10px;"></div>
                }
                
            </Template>
        </GridColumn>

    </GridColumns>
</TelerikGrid>

@code {
        Course[] courses { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        courses = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Course[]>("Course");
    }

}
```